# Cannot find symbol JdbcTypeCode

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, maven, spring-jdbc

My Springboot maven application gives "symbol not found error" during build.

```
#13 552.4 [ERROR] /build/src/main/java/com/../Employee.java:[26,32] error: cannot find symbol
#13 552.4 [ERROR]   symbol:   class JdbcTypeCode
#13 552.4 [ERROR]   location: package org.hibernate.annotations
#13 552.4 [ERROR] /build/src/main/java/com/../Employee.java:[27,25] error: cannot find symbol
#13 552.4 [ERROR]   symbol:   class SqlTypes
#13 552.4 [ERROR]   location: package org.hibernate.type
```

I have added following to my pom.xml still I get the above error.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing here?

Not sure how to fix these. Did some search for maven dependency for following Classes the above two hibernate dependencies are only mentioned.

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcTypeCode;
import org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes;
```

Comment: Remove `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-commons-annotations`. The `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` already pulls in the proper dependencies. If you want a different hibernate version add `<hibernate.version>6.2.4.Final</hibernate.version>` to your `<properties>` in your `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-commons-annotations` dependencies. The `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` already pulls in the proper dependencies. This applies to all starters BTW, so if you have `spring-boot-starter-validation` in there and `hibernate-validator` don't do that.

If you want a different hibernate version add `<hibernate.version>6.2.4.Final</hibernate.version>` to your `<properties>` in your `pom.xml`.

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For the version override:

```xml
<properties>
  <java.version>17</java.version>
  <hibernate.version>6.2.4.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```